# Place button group at the far right side of a header with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've managed to place a button group at the far side of a header (H1/H2/H3). However, I don't know how to make the button float vertically in the middle. It just stays at the top. I tried using `margin-top` but since it's a fixed value it won't be dynamically placed in the middle.

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
<div class="container">
  <section>
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1 class="pull-left">
        The header
      </h1>
      <div class="pull-right">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">
            Actions
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Another Action</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    Contents
  </section>
</div>
```

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aurorius/PKrUC/

Comment: Better can you show your css code, not bootstrap code

Comment: @Selva In this case I would say it isn't, since bootstrap is a framework meant to solve a lot of CSS fidgeting automatically. It would've been a good idea to post actual HTML though, instead of HTML templating language (since that might confuse some).

Answer (score 172, accepted):

This how to get a button lined up with the header in Bootstrap 3.2, 3.3 without any additional CSS in case anyone is coming here from Google.

**Option 1**

http://jsfiddle.net/ypaL5nko/

```
<div class='page-header'>
  <div class='btn-toolbar pull-right'>
    <div class='btn-group'>
      <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Button Text</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2>Header Text</h2>
</div>
```

The button group is optional if you're only using a single button.

**Option 2**

http://jsfiddle.net/sLdnae3q/

```
<h1>
  <span>Header Text</span>
  <button class='btn btn-primary pull-right'>Button Text</button>
</h1>
<hr/>
```

Comment: This also worked well for me in putting a button near the top right hand side of a well. It was not right in the corner, but it was near the corner.

Comment: Option 1 will display better when there is overlap because of long header text or small screens.

Comment: Option 2 is also not semantically correct, and I wonder what screen readers would end up with reading that...

Comment: The button group is optional even if you're using several buttons.

Comment: Option 2 only succeeds in the specific case of using `<h1>` and `'btn-primary'`, due to a happy coincidence of default sizes. Try doing it with a `<h4>`...

Comment: Can heading be before button in first option. Just saying, since kinda usual behaviour is to read markup, from top to bottom as text from right to left?

Comment: Warning! If you are using option 1, you'll end up your button being above the headings if the line wraps.

Comment: `float-right` replaces `pull-right` in Bootstrap 4: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/

Answer (score 9):

Try this css code

```
.btn-group.my-class{
  bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
}
```

Dynamic header on H1/H2/H3 and may be H4

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PKrUC/2/

Comment: This seems to work, but do I really have to put that 10px? Wouldn't that make too fixed? BTW, since the `page-header` height is `60px` and the `btn-group` height is `30px`, thus, to place it in the middle, I should put it as `top: 15px`, right?

Comment: This code will possibly (and probably) screw up any other `.btn-group` elements in your HTML. At least add a specific class to this specific instance of it and use that as a CSS selector instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using a float disables te `display:inline-block;` property, making it float to the top.

Just add the bootstrap class `text-right` to the container to keep the vertical align intact.

Comment: you make a good point about floating makes the elements float to the top. But your solution does not seem to work, do you have a fiddle or codepen where you can show us what you did?